# Can I transform the CVXPY indicator transform into a 0/1 binary rather than 0/infty binary?

Tags: transform, indicator, cvxpy

**Here's my code:**

import cvxpy as cp

c = cp.Variable(1)

Then I have a numpy.ndarray *m* and a constraint

constraint = [m >= c].

I next construct the indicator

*idx = cp.transforms.indicator(constraint)*

At this stage, I encounter two issues:

**a) When I evaluate idx in my console window, I get the following error:**

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py_cvx\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\expression.py", line 159, in is_constant
    return self.**is_constant
AttributeError: 'indicator' object has no attribute '_Expression__is_constant'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py_cvx\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 224, in catch_format_error
    r = method(self, *args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py_cvx\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 702, in __call**
    printer.pretty(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py_cvx\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py", line 402, in pretty
    return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py_cvx\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py", line 697, in _repr_pprint
    output = repr(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py_cvx\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\expression.py", line 100, in **repr**
    return "Expression(%s, %s, %s)" % (self.curvature,
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py_cvx\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\expression.py", line 121, in curvature
    if self.is_constant():
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py_cvx\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\expression.py", line 162, in is_constant
    arg.is_constant() for arg in self.args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py_cvx\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\expression.py", line 162, in 
    arg.is_constant() for arg in self.args)
AttributeError: 'Inequality' object has no attribute 'is_constant'

**b) I'd like the indicator to return 1 if true and 0 if false, rather than 0 if true and infty if false. My thoughts were around the following solution:**

*idx = cp.transforms.indicator(constraint) == 0*

Would that work once above error/issue is resolved?

Thanks for your reply.
Ralf

Comment: Put all your codes in a separate format. This will give better readability to the readers. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks